AWS Amplify Gen 2 - How to get refresh token?
Is there a way to get user refresh token for Cognito using AWS Amplify Gen 2?
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify"
import { signIn, signOut, getCurrentUser, fetchAuthSession } from "aws-amplify/auth"

const session: AuthSession = await fetchAuthSession();

'session.tokens' contains the only accessToken and idToken. I'd like to store refresh token in backend for future needs.
Thank you.

Do you find a way? If yes, please, answer your own question. We also have same problem

A hacky way would be to read it from the localStorage after the user has logged in:
export function getRefreshTokenFromLocalStorage() {
  const lastUserKey = `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.${clientId}.LastAuthUser`;
  const lastUser = localStorage.getItem(lastUserKey);
  const refreshTokenKey = `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.${clientId}.${lastUser}.refreshToken`;
  return localStorage.getItem(refreshTokenKey);
}

where clientId is the user pool client ID used in the Cognito configuration.
Note: This may break if aws-amplify changes its internal logic. And it won't work if you configured Amplify to use a different kind of storage (the default is a localStorage though).
It seems to be intentional that the Amplify team hid it (from here):

Also note that we no longer return refreshToken or clockDrift with the
AuthSession. These values are used under the hood to refresh/validate
the user session.

It would be nice to have it exposed though (in my case, it is about showing the user a countdown before refreshToken expires and then logging them out). Maybe someone could open an issue.
